# Convert pandas dataframe to datasetDict

Tags: pandas, huggingface-datasets

I cannot find anywhere how to convert a pandas dataframe to type `datasets.dataset_dict.DatasetDict`, for optimal use in a BERT workflow with a huggingface model. Take these simple dataframes, for example.

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame({
     "label" : [1, 2, 3],
     "text" : ["apple", "pear", "strawberry"]
})

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
     "label" : [2, 2, 1],
     "text" : ["banana", "pear", "apple"]
})
```

What is the most efficient way to convert these to the type above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possibility is to first create two Datasets and then join them:

```
import datasets
import pandas as pd


train_df = pd.DataFrame({
     "label" : [1, 2, 3],
     "text" : ["apple", "pear", "strawberry"]
})

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
     "label" : [2, 2, 1],
     "text" : ["banana", "pear", "apple"]
})

train_dataset = Dataset.from_dict(train_df)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_dict(test_df)
my_dataset_dict = datasets.DatasetDict({"train":train_dataset,"test":test_dataset})
```

The result is:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['label', 'text'],
        num_rows: 3
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['label', 'text'],
        num_rows: 3
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't you have to do `Dataset.from_pandas(train_df)` and `Dataset.from_pandas(test_df)` instead of using the from_dict?

Comment: @VincentClaes You can use `.from_dict()` as long as there are no missing values.